# npm start cause error React native is not installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I want to learn React Native and start from [Facebook Github][1], So have installed the node.js V8.114 , then run below command on command prompt

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app

create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

Everything went right, but when I run the `npm start`  , this error caused:

> Error: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your
>   project directory. 16:36:21: Error starting packager: Error: Couldn't
>   start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
>       at C:\xdl\src\Project.js:1329:11
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (C:\Users\Riazati\AwesomeProject\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1735:191)
>       at C:\Users\Riazati\AwesomeProject\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1735:361
>       at  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 start
>   script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is recommended to use `yarn` with react, much quicker and reliable with react. If you already installed `yarn` then use `yarn start`. If there is still error then `yarn install`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you npm is updated `npm install -g npm@latest` delete the folder, then re-run the build process

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install`, like the error message tells you to.

Answer (score 0):

Once you cd to the project try running ‘npm install’ or ‘yarn’ then you could try running ‘react-native run-ios’ or ‘react-native run-android’

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `node modules` and then run `npm install` or `yarn install` worked for me!!
Cheers.